# Can we run a .ipynb file in python shell after converting it as .py file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a .ipynb after converting it to .py file(in jupyter notebook i downloaded it as text file and changed its extension to .py). Not when I execute command

```
>>python my_file.py
```

It gives me this error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled2.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\python2\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\python2\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 35, in <module>
    from nltk.probability import FreqDist
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\python2\lib\site-packages\nltk\probability.py", line 333
    print("%*s" % (width, samples[i]), end=" ")
```

I don't have much python experience. Please pardon me if this question is out of context.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `.ipynb` to `.py` just open `File -> Download as -> Python(.py)` from Jupyter Notebook. Then you can run it in python as long as your python code in jupyter is correct and you run from same environment.

Have you install nltk module in your machine? if haven't you can install it with `pip install nltk`